# Periodic timers in python, with small period

Tags: python, timer

Using the Timer class and restarting the timer in the callable, is the standard method of running a periodic timer in the background in python.

This has two major drawbacks:

- it is not really periodic: setup of the timer, ...
- it creates a new thread for each period

Is there an alternative to the Timer class? I have taken a look at the sched class, but running in the MainThread will block it, and it is not recommended to run it in a multithreaded environment.

How can I have a high frequency periodic timer (100 ms period) in python, for example to regularly empty a document queue when collecting bulk data to send to a database?

Comment: Don't do it, time is no good "event" for things like that, just use a queue and count the items/size threshold to determine when it is about time to push the data.

Comment: Size alone won't cut it. Let's say my threshold is 10 documents, and I put 9 documents in the queue. I have no more data, just 9 documents. But since the threshold is not reached, the data won't be pushed. Thus, a combination of size and ellapsed time is needed to make sure that short bursts of data are pushed within a maximum timeframe. This is what I am using: a queue and a periodic timer. Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Threashold the total count of **bytes** in the queue.

Comment: @drahnr: What does that solve? My threshold is 10000 bytes, I put only 9999 bytes in the queue. It will never be sent. The threshold is useful to send the documents before the queue becomes *too big*, but to make sure the documents are indeed sent, a timer is needed. I can see no other way of guaranteeing that, except *forcing* flushing  from the upper layer, which is exactly what I want to avoid. The library managing the comunication must make sure that the data is delivered in an efficient way.

Comment: you know when a document is `done` (lets say it's a string which should be `\0` terminated, just an example, it is pretty much the same for files on disk (EOF event)). So you _know_ when one document is done and can flush the buffer additionally to a byte-count based threshold. At least that is would I would do.

Comment: @drahnr: It is not a document, it is a bunch of documents which get collected and sent to the database as a bulk request (to improve performance). And no, I have no indication of when there is no more data to be sent. The upper layer knows it, of course, but I want to offer a simple interface to the upper layer: it must not care about the internal implementation. Specifically, I want to avoid forcing the upper layer to flush the queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come up with the following alternative:

```
import threading
import time

class PeriodicThread(StoppableThread):
    '''Similar to a Timer(), but uses only one thread, stops cleanly and exits when the main thread exits'''

    def __init__ (self, period, callable, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PeriodicThread, self).__init__()
        self.period   = period
        self.args     = args
        self.callable = callable
        self.kwargs   = kwargs
        self.daemon   = True

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            time.sleep(self.period)
```